# CSV written out by python is completely blank in Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a simple dict that I'm writing to a csv file and it looks fine when I view it on the server, but it is completely blank in excel.

```
csvOutput = {'http://www.test.com/': 'This source is currently in the system.', 'http://test.com/': 'This source is not currently in the system.', 'http://www.test.com/': 'This source is currently in the system.'}

writer = csv.writer(open(csvFileName, 'wb'), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, dialect='excel')
for key, value in csvOutput.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Thanks for your help!

And here is what I see in the file with vim:

```
http://www.test.com/,This source is currently in the system.
http://test.com/,This source is not currently in the system.  
http://www.test.com/,This source is currently in the system.
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you open the file in a text editor - what do you see?

Comment: What happens if you 'print' the output rather than write it?

Comment: I put the editor output above, thanks!  If I print rather than write, it looks just like the dict above.

Comment: That's a perfectly valid CSV file, and should be possible to open in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your help!  It was user error, but answering your inquiries helped me catch myself.  I was sending the file somewhere before I closed it. Duh...

```
for key, value in csvOutput.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])

f1.close() # I hadn't closed it here.

f2 = open(csvFileName)
jira.add_attachment(issueKey, f)
f2.close()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your code is

```
csvOutput={}
writer = csv.writer(open(csvFileName, 'wb'), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, dialect='excel')
for key, value in csvOutput.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

there is nothing to write so the file is empty

quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE should probably not used

Comment: Let me add that above, just a second.

Comment: Removing quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE seems to have no effect in my case.

Comment: `w = csv.writer(sys.stdout,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE);w.writerow(['hello"','"world'])` lead to exception